# selecting max values in relational tables with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 tables that are related to each other, I connect to other tables with the id cv in the CV Table. As a result of my query, I want to get the max ID_IS row in the CV_IS table and the max ID_EGITIM row in the cv_etm table.
So I want to return a single record for each cv_id as a result of my query.

My sample table information is as follows :

[image]

linq code :

```
 var IdList = (from e in db.CV
                              join d in db.CV_IS
                              on e.ID_CV equals d.ID_CV into ps
                              from d in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   join f in db.CV_ETM
                                   on e.ID_CV equals f.ID_CV into ps1
                                   from f in ps1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              select new CvViewModel
                              {
                                  ADI = e.ADI,
                                  SOYADI = e.SOYADI,
                                  POZISYON = ps.OrderByDescending(t => t.ID_IS).Select(t => t.POISITION).FirstOrDefault() ?? String.Empty,
                                  OKUL = ps1.OrderByDescending(y => y.ID_EGITIM).Select(y => y.OKUL).FirstOrDefault() ?? String.Empty,
                                  BOLUM = ps1.OrderByDescending(z => z.ID_EGITIM).Select(z => z.BOLUM).FirstOrDefault() ?? String.Empty}).toList();
```

With the above linq query, the output is as follows :

[image]

how can I return a single row result for each person?

Comment: you mean single result for each person?

Comment: yes , i mean it

Comment: What type of LINQ is this? Also, use navigation properties, don't join, then this will be much easier.

Comment: Can you show me how to use?

Comment: No, I don't know your class model and I don't know what type of LINQ you're using. Entity Framework probably. If so, which version?

Comment: you have to change join section don't join with all table join with max person, to be honest it's easy to do :) you gone figure it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
var IdList = from result in (
                from e in db.CV
                join d in db.CV_IS on e.ID_CV equals d.ID_CV into ps
                from d in ps.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                join f in db.CV_ETM on e.ID_CV equals f.ID_CV
                group new {e,d,f} by e.ID_CV into g
                select g.OrderByDescending(x =>{x.d.ID_IS,x.f.ID_EGITIM}).First()
             )
             select new CvViewModel
             {
                ADI = result.e.ADI,
                SOYADI = result.e.SOYADI,
                POZISYON = result.d.POISITION,
                OKUL = result.f.OKUL),
                BOLUM = result.f.BOLUM)
             };
```

Comment: @Hakanözel Incorrect result or syntax error?

Comment: select g.OrderByDescending(x =>{x.d.ID_IS,x.f.ID_EGITIM}).First() there is syntax error

Comment: change it to select g.OrderByDescending(x =>x.d.ID_IS).ThenByDescending(x=>x.f.ID_EGITIM).First()

Comment: partially this query worked , but if there is no cv_id in cv_is and cv_etm, that record does not come, I want it to come even if it is null . Actually like left join.

Comment: I added the following line, the problem is solved , thank you                                                 join f in db.CV_EGITIM on e.ID_CV equals f.ID_CV into c
                 from f in c.DefaultIfEmpty()